# how keep the terminal running on nvim after some command?

Tags: terminal, neovim

Exemple:

if I run `:ter exemple.sh`

the terminal will run the script and then return `[Process exited 0]`

I want to keep the terminal open after that.

Comment: The only "solution" to me until now is something create keymap where I enter in insert mode and do changes, but should have some better way

keymap.set("n", "<leader>1", ":ter<CR>i<CR>setproxy<CR>")

Comment: I recommend trying https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim